# How to solve application responsivness issue in C#

Tags: c#, arraylist

I am trying to implement a genetic algorithm in c#. The genetic has crossover method  and mutation method. The population size is 5 chromosomes where each chromosome is a 2d array of integers (matrix 10x10) The genetic should loop 50 times and call crossover and mutation each loop as follows:

```
  DateTime startTiming = DateTime.Now;

        TimeSpan startGenetic;


        // Make a population for each layer - as we have 4 layers, thus 4 population arrays after the intial eavaluation for the intial population and have differernt values in the aterations > 1 
        static List<int[,]> populationLayer1 = new List<int[,]>();
        static List<int[,]> populationLayer2 = new List<int[,]>();
        static List<int[,]> populationLayer3 = new List<int[,]>();
        static List<int[,]> populationLayer4 = new List<int[,]>();

        // 4 layers - we need 4 arrays 
        double[,] FitnessValLayer1 = new double[5, 2]; // for all "5" chromosome we store "2" Values : (Fitness Value - Fitness Ratio) in each layer (as we have 4 layers)
        double[,] FitnessValLayer2 = new double[5, 2]; // for all "5" chromosome we store "2" Values : (Fitness Value - Fitness Ratio) in each layer (as we have 4 layers)
        double[,] FitnessValLayer3 = new double[5, 2]; // for all "5" chromosome we store "2" Values : (Fitness Value - Fitness Ratio) in each layer (as we have 4 layers)
        double[,] FitnessValLayer4 = new double[5, 2]; // for all "5" chromosome we store "2" Values : (Fitness Value - Fitness Ratio) in each layer (as we have 4 layers)

        // 4 RouletteWeel values because of the 4 layers
        int[] RouletteWheelLayer1 = new int[10];
        int[] RouletteWheelLayer2 = new int[10];
        int[] RouletteWheelLayer3 = new int[10];
        int[] RouletteWheelLayer4 = new int[10];

        public async Task Genetic_Algorithm(List<int[,]> population)

        {

            cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            //In this step just duplicate the initial population 
            populationLayer1 = population.ToList();
            populationLayer2 = population.ToList();
            populationLayer3 = population.ToList();
            populationLayer4 = population.ToList();

            int round = 0;



            for (geneticIteration = 0; geneticIteration < minIteration; geneticIteration++)
            {


                round = geneticIteration;

                //----------------------//
                //Calculate Fitness 
                try
                {
                    // Calculate the fitness Function and the Fitness Ratio
                    await FitnessFunctionAsync(populationLayer1, populationLayer2, populationLayer3, populationLayer4, cancelSource.Token); // Fitness Function
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    // Write output to the file.
                    Trace.Write("when calling (FitnessFunctionAsync)..." + ex.Message);
                    Trace.Flush();

                }

                //----------------------//
                // To Do : 
                //get 4 arrays for the fitness for each layer 


                //----------------------//
                // Note : Each layer has different values for fitness so the changes on the population will not be the same in the 4 layers 
                //---------------------//

                    //RouletteWeel 
                    RouletteWheelLayer1 = RouletteWheel_Selection(FitnessValLayer1);
                    RouletteWheelLayer2 = RouletteWheel_Selection(FitnessValLayer2);
                    RouletteWheelLayer3 = RouletteWheel_Selection(FitnessValLayer3);
                    RouletteWheelLayer4 = RouletteWheel_Selection(FitnessValLayer4);


                    //Crossover 
                   // populationLayer1 = CrosssOver(RouletteWheelLayer1, populationLayer1);
                    //populationLayer2 = CrosssOver(RouletteWheelLayer2, populationLayer2);
                   // populationLayer3 = CrosssOver(RouletteWheelLayer3, populationLayer3);
                    //populationLayer4 = CrosssOver(RouletteWheelLayer4, populationLayer4);

                    //Mutation 
                    //populationLayer1 = Mutation(RouletteWheelLayer1, populationLayer1);
                   // populationLayer2 = Mutation(RouletteWheelLayer2, populationLayer2);
                   // populationLayer3 = Mutation(RouletteWheelLayer3, populationLayer3);
                    //populationLayer4 = Mutation(RouletteWheelLayer4, populationLayer4);


                    // 4 layers - re-intialize  
                     FitnessValLayer1 = new double[5, 2]; 
                     FitnessValLayer2 = new double[5, 2]; 
                     FitnessValLayer3 = new double[5, 2]; 
                     FitnessValLayer4 = new double[5, 2]; 

                    // 4 RouletteWeel - re-intialize 
                     RouletteWheelLayer1 = new int[10];
                     RouletteWheelLayer2 = new int[10];
                     RouletteWheelLayer3 = new int[10];
                     RouletteWheelLayer4 = new int[10];


            }


            InvokeUpdateControls();


        }
```

Unfortunately, I got my application not response when implement the crossover or mutation i.e. when the probabilities are satisfied. The following are the two methods:

```
public List<int[,]> CrosssOver(int[] RouletteWheel, List<int[,]> population)
        {


            double rndNumber1 = 0.0;

            int rndNumber2 = 0;

            Random rnd = new Random();

            int chrom1 = 0;

            int chrom2 = 0;



            for (int i = 0; i < population.Count; i++) // For all Chromosomes
            {
                rndNumber1 = rnd.Next(0, 11) / 10.00; // generate a random number to check the probability for crossover

                chrom1 = RouletteWheel[rnd.Next(0, 10)];

                chrom2 = RouletteWheel[rnd.Next(0, 10)];

                if (rndNumber1 <= Pc) /* check if we will do Crossover */
                {

                    rndNumber2 = rnd.Next(0, rows - 1); // determine the crossover point randomly by generating number between 0 and rows-1


                    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
                    {


                        for (int v = 0; v < columns; v++)
                        {



                            if (j == rndNumber2) /* copy from same chromosome */
                            {

                                try
                                {
                                    population[chrom1][j, v] = population[chrom2][j, v];
                                }

                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    // Write output to the file.
                                    Trace.Write("crossover..." + ex.Message);
                                    Trace.Flush();
                                    return population;

                                }

                            }


                        }

                    }

                }

            }



            return population;

        } // end-cross-over
```

The mutation method:

```
 public List<int[,]> Mutation(int[] RouletteWheel, List<int[,]> population)
        {

            double rndNumber1 = 0.0;

            int chrom1 = 0;

            int rndNumber2 = 0;

            Random rnd = new Random();


            for (int i = 0; i < population.Count; i++) // For all Chromosomes
            {
                rndNumber1 = rnd.Next(0, 11) / 100.00; // generate a random number between 0 and 10 and divide result by 100

                chrom1 = RouletteWheel[rnd.Next(0, 10)];

                if (rndNumber1 <= Pm) /* check if we will do Crossover */
                {

                    rndNumber2 = rnd.Next(0, rows); // determine the crossover point randomly by generating number between 0 and rows -1 


                    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
                    {


                        for (int v = 0; v < columns; v++)
                        {



                            if (j == rndNumber2) /* Mutate the cell that is equal to 1 */
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    if (population[chrom1][j, v] == 0)
                                    {
                                        population[chrom1][j, v] = 1;
                                    }

                                }

                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    // Write output to the file.
                                    Trace.Write("mutation..." + ex.Message);
                                    Trace.Flush();
                                    return population;

                                }

                            }


                        }

                    }

                }

            }


            return population;


        }
```

My app is stuck because of these methods... 
I need to move to the next iteration if the mutation and crossover are successfully completed.

Comment: You want to move to the next iteration of `for (int i = 0; i < population.Count; i++)` ?

Comment: @na2axl : I need to move to the next iteration if the computations in the called methods inside the loop completed successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only real answer in a case like this is to move the offending code into a separate thread so the main thread remains available to pump the message queue.

Make sure it can't be triggered twice, make sure nothing else can write the data while it's running and be **very** wary of even reading any of the data (for example, to display intermediate results) in any other thread.